# Finding limit when the change of variable is not one-to-one

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to rigorously prove that $\displaystyle L= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^{-1}x}{x} =1$, without using l'hospital rule.

When we let $\sin y = x$, can I write $\displaystyle L= \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin^{-1}(\sin y)}{\sin y}= \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{\sin y}=1$ ?

Or, do I need an argument like

$\displaystyle L= \lim_{y\to k\pi} \frac{\sin^{-1}(\sin y)}{\sin y}= \lim_{y \to k\pi}\frac{y-k\pi}{\sin y}=\lim_{y \to k\pi}\frac{y-k\pi}{\sin (y-k\pi)}= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{\sin z}=1$?

What are the assumptions in each step above? For example, "if $y$ is close enough to $k\pi$, then $\sin y$ is one-to-one. Otherwise, the first equality above might not be true" etc.

Comment: You first idea is correct. You can make it more formal, setting $y=\arcsin x$. B.t.w., preferably use the mathematical name of the function, not $\sin^{-1}$, which is the name for hand-held calculator, given the limited space available on a key.

Comment: @Bernard: Although the notation $\sin^{-1}$ has its shortcomings, it is a pretty standard notation in Indian math texts and when one learns this notation for the first time, it always comes with a *warning* that $(-1)$ is not an exponent here, but rather the notation for inverse function so that students don't write $\sin^{-1}x = 1/\sin x$. The notation $\arcsin$ appears to be without any shortcomings and perhaps more popular internationally.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: What I criticize about the `^–1` notation, is mainly that it tends to let beginners think the sine function is bijective. Furthermore arcsin, etymologically, is more telling than a generic notation.

Comment: @Bernard. If you are French, I totally understand your point. These are aong the amazing things : when at was at university, I never heard about $\csc(x)$ or $\sec(x)$ forgetting all the other. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Je le suis. I must say when I was about to  pass my ‘baccalauréat’ (not sure whether I should use French guillemets or British quotes here…), there was an intensive program on trigonometry, « résolution des triangles » and so on, but I didn't hear about secant and cosecant either.

Comment: If you want to contact me, my e-mail address is in my profile. Cheers.

Comment: @Bernard. It's a European thing. In Belgium and Holland they also refrain from using sec, csc and cot in textbooks (and I have couple of those from which I studied). But in North America, these notations are very common from day one when a student learns about trig...

Comment: @imranfat: I learnt cotantgent, not the others. We knew these existed, of course, but they were considered old stuff, useful only for land-surveyors. Just as everyone knows the decimal logarithm, but no one sees the necessity to study it *per se* as a function